# I'm making a development board for ESP32 S2 board, I want to achieve IEC61000-4-2 (level 4) ESD protection on the connectors

Tags: protection, esd

I am using a 4 channel TVS(diode) array that has a max clamping voltage of 12V. I have a voltage devidor to translate 5V to 2.5V. So I asume that max clamped input is 6V if an ESD event occurs.

I read that the ESP32-S2 I/O pins are 3.3V tolerant. **I am going to set my I/O pins to input so would they than be 6V tolerant?**

See picture for schematic

[image: Circuit for analog connector to ESP32-S2]

Comment: Silabs have an app note that might be of assistance: https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN895.pdf.  Note that ESD are fast pulses, so pcb layout is critical and consider flash-over where the voltage simply jumps to a more convenient point and bypasses your protection.

Comment: Thx, I wil look into it

Answer (score 0):

MCU IO pins are not 6V tolerant. Generally they tolerate 3.3V plus some protection clamp diode voltage at some clamp current. For ESP32 voltage is said to b 3.6V at 3.3V supply but no clamping current was in the data sheet.

Because you have a voltage divider, and with 2k from IO pin to 6V, so it might momentarily handle the resulting 1mA of clamping current.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I totaly forgot about the resistor limiting the current. Now I have 3 options for better protection: 

1) increase resistors of the voltage devidor to lower the input current

2) add an opamp buffer that can handle 6V

3) change the voltage devider for 5V to 1V because that is the refrence voltage of ESP32-S2.

I think the best solution is 3 because it is simpel and it does not reduce ADC accuracy.